# How to call dialogfragment from another fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm really new in android development, hope you guys can help me in my problem. I had already search for any solution but none of it works.
I have 6 fragments for scrollable tabs, then each tabs has ADD TO CART buttons, if I click that button a fragment dialog should appear. In my case, there is this error.

> Error:(37, 13) error: no suitable method found for show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,String)
>   method DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentManager)
>   method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to FragmentTransaction)

Heres my code by the way for the fragment to call the DialogFragment.

```
package info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments;

    import android.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}

public void toDiagCartFragment(View v){
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    CartFragment cart = new CartFragment();
    cart.show(manager, "My Cart");
}

}
```

This the code for DialogFragment to be called by OneFragment

```
package info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments;

  import android.app.DialogFragment;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;

  import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;


 public class CartFragment extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart2, null);
}
}
```

Seems like the error is in the OneFragment.java

Heres my output by the way.
[image: This is the fragment to call the dialog]

[image: This is suppose to be the dialog]

_I really appreciate for any answers, just please be nice to me
.I really don't know how to do it . :(
.Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show DialogFragment from another DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16540186/show-dialogfragment-from-another-dialogfragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `OneFragment` belongs to support library fragment while `CartFragment` doesn't. you need to either modify `CartFragment` to support library or `OneFragment` to default Fragment. and modifying CartFragment to support library fragment will be better as support library has more functionality.

Comment: _how am I going to modify my CartFragment to support library fragment ?

Comment: replace `import android.app.DialogFragment;` with
 `import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;` in `CartFragment.java`

Answer (score 1):

your error says your answer clearly.

> type mismatch

your dialogFragment has `android.app.FragmentManager` and you are calling `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`. you should use `getSupportFragmentManger()` insted of `getFragmentManager();`

first of all replace your cartFragment import to this,

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

and create this method.

```
public static CartFragment newInstance() {
        CartFragment dialog = new CartFragment ();
        return dialog;
    }
```

and in your one_fragment use like this.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();            
CartFragment newFragment = CartFragment .newInstance();
newFragment.show(ft, "My Cart");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a version mismatch. Instead of using getFragmentManager(), use getSupportFragmentManager() as you are using the support library version of Fragments.

Replace

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
```

with

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: _if I change it into that, it will change into another error

Error:(37, 13) error: no suitable method found for show(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager,String)
method DialogFragment.show(android.app.FragmentManager,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.app.FragmentManager)
method DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to FragmentTransaction)